# SSRS Recurrence Items from Calender List Sharepoint - The SharePoint list query is not valid: The XML element QueryOptions in the query is not valid

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services

I am trying to grab all items in the next upcoming week from a sharepoint list, some of these may be recurring items that have been created a few months back. I am getting the below error:

The SharePoint list query is not valid: The XML element QueryOptions in the query is not valid.

This is my sharepoint query designer code in SSRS:

```
<RSSharePointList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ListName>Change Control</ListName>
 <Query>
 <Where>
  <DateRangesOverlap>
  <FieldRef Name='EventDate' />
  <FieldRef Name='EndDate' />
  <FieldRef Name='RecurrenceID' />
  </DateRangesOverlap>
 </Where>
 </Query>
<QueryOptions>
 <ExpandRecurrence>TRUE</ExpandRecurrence>
 <ViewAttributes Scope='RecursiveAll' />
 </QueryOptions>
  <ViewFields>
    <FieldRef Name="Title" />
    <FieldRef Name="Originators_x0020_Name" />
    <FieldRef Name="EventDate" />
    <FieldRef Name="EndDate" />
    <FieldRef Name="ID" />
    <FieldRef Name="RecurrenceID" />
    <FieldRef Name="RecurrenceData" />
    <FieldRef Name="Staff_x0020_Involved_x0020_with_" />
  </ViewFields>
</RSSharePointList>
```

Comment: I'm not an SSRS expert but I know SP & CAML - that's a valid CAML query. I wonder if the SharePoint List Query in SSRS does not support the full range of CAML (I see other posts online suggesting so). If that's the case, perhaps consider using an "XML Data Source" inside SSRS and hook that up to a SharePoint web service that does support the full range of CAML queries. Example here: http://tavislovell.com/using-ssrs-with-sharepoint-library-folders/

Comment: @Stevangelista - that seems to work but having issues pulling out all my item names in the list.

Comment: Pulling out all your item names?

Comment: Managed to figure it out. I put <viewName> in my CAML query and it looks at a particular view on sharepoint and pulls out all the columns from that view. However issue now it keeps picking up the default view? Doesnt seem to work if I pick another public or private view. Keeps giving me the same columns and same rows.

Comment: Are you saying the `<ViewFields>` element is having no impact on your query? Which web service are you calling & what does your revised query look like?

Comment: Think I've managed to solve it. It picks up any views that are a list public view. But if the public view is a calendar view it does not work.

Comment: In light of that, I'll expand upon my initial comment & post it as an answer as it sounds like that solved your challenge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've posted is indeed a valid CAML query but it's clear the SharePoint List Query in SSRS does not support the full range of CAML ([reference](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ac25460d-ca11-48a1-947b-488f52413ad7/caml-query-in-ssrs-reports?forum=sqlreportingservices)).

Instead you should setup an "XML Data Source" inside SSRS and hook that up to a SharePoint web service that does support the full range of CAML queries.

Summary of steps:

1. Open report builder
2. Right click the “Data Sources” folder and select “Add Data Source”
3. Enter “XMLTest” as the data source name
4. Select “Use a connection embedded in my report”
5. Select “XML” as the “Connection Type”
6. For the connection string you’ll want to enter the URL to your site plus “/_vti_bin/lists.asmx”. (You can verify the connection string by entering it into your web browser. Doing so should return a list of web services for the site.)
7. Click on the “Credentials” menu item on the left hand side of the “Data Source Properties” window
8. Select the option “Use the current Windows user. Kerberos delegation might be required.”
9. Click the “OK” button on the “Data Source Properties” window.

Source: http://tavislovell.com/using-ssrs-with-sharepoint-library-folders/