# Is is possible for SSRS to query a sharepoint view rather than a list?

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services

Is is possible for SSRS to query a sharepoint view rather than a list ?

Comment: You can query the Content DB.

Comment: If I don't have access to the DB behind a sharepoint list. There is a way to select sharepoint list as a data source on SSRS, but I guess not possible to look at a public view? Issue is I am trying to view future events that are recurring items, these are visible as a calendar view on sharepoint but not on the list itself.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to try & "query" the Calendar View - you just need the proper CAML to query an Events list that breaks out all the occurrences of a recurring Event as individual items.

The key is a combination of the `<DaveRangesOverlap>` operator and the `<ExpandRecurrence>` query option:

```
<Query>
    <Where>
        <DateRangesOverlap>
            <FieldRef Name="EventDate"/>
            <FieldRef Name="EndDate"/>
            <FieldRef Name="RecurrenceID"/>
            <Value Type="DateTime">
                <DEFAULT/>
            </Value>
        </DateRangesOverlap>
    </Where>
</Query>
<QueryOptions>
    <ExpandRecurrence>True</ExpandRecurrence>
</QueryOptions>
```

Possible values within the `<Value Type=DateTime>` element inside the `<DateRangesOverlap>` operator are:

- `<Today/>` = all the data, including recurring item instances, that would appear in the **current** day View in the native SP list
- `<Week/>` = all the data, including recurring item instances, that would appear in the **current** week View in the native SP list
- `<Month/>` = all the data, including recurring item instances, that would appear in the **current** month View in the native SP list (*Note*: this often includes leading or trailing data from the end of the previous month and/or the beginning of the following month as the Calendar Month View in SharePoint displays them)
- `<Now/>` = returns data, including recurring item instances, that occurs in the **future** (appears to have a range out to up to 2 years; could be reduced with additional `<Where>` filters.
- `<DEFAULT/>` = returns data, including recurring item instances, based on the Calendar default

EDIT: Just came across your other SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44904429/ssrs-recurrence-items-from-calender-list-sharepoint-the-sharepoint-list-query); you're on the right track...